# autohotkey Media_Play_Pause not mapped to Pause but mapped to ^Space

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-events, key-bindings

Since Spotify changed to their latest version the old Play/Pause through `ControlSend, ahk_parent, {space}, ahk_class SpotifyMainWindow` stopped working.

It seems Spotify can now capture the Media keys and as suggested by other members the following works:

```
^Space::Media_Play_Pause
```

HOWEVER mapping to the Pause key doesn't work.

```
Pause::Media_Play_Pause
```

Any idea why???

FYI here is the scan of the keys:

Working (^Space):

```
VK  SC  Type    Up/Dn   Elapsed Key     Window
----------------------------------------------    
A2  01D     d   1.61    LControl        
20  039 h   d   0.14    Space           
B3  022 i   d   0.00    Media_Play_Pause    
20  039 h   u   0.13    Space           
B3  022 i   u   0.00    Media_Play_Pause    
A2  01D     u   0.13    LControl
```

Not working (Pause):

```
13  045 h   d   1.81    Pause           
B3  022 i   d   0.00    Media_Play_Pause    
13  045 h   u   0.16    Pause           
B3  022 i   u   0.00    Media_Play_Pause
```

Another intriguing point is that neither of the following Send commands work:

```
Send {VKB3SC022} 
Send {Media_Play_Pause}
```

Comment: This is weird - all of your three "not working" issues work perfectly fine for me. Might have something to do with your keyboard configuration?

Comment: Thank you for checking Blauhim. I am using a Logitech K800 wireless keyboard, I will try with a wired keyboard as well as on another PC. Could it have something to do with configuration settings such as Sendmode?? 
Maybe that instead of adding this to my large autohotkey.ahk I could run a short script with only these settings? Could you let me know if you use any particular global setting?

Comment: I tried it in a fresh ahk script with nothing else in it. SendMode defaults to Event* looked it up just now

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely lost. I tried with a wired keyboard, I killed logitech setpoint as well as Microsoft's driver (leftover from MS mouse). I tried on a laptop and I have the same behavior. Pause mapping to Media_Play_Pause won't work – it sends the proper key but Spotify nor MediaMonkey detect it... Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that for media_play_pause, the UpDn column is 0.00
Does this not mean that the key is not being "Held" for any time?
Try either:

```
Send {media_play_pause down}
Sleep 50
Send {media_play_pause up}
```

Or:

```
SetKeyDelay, 0, 50
[...]
Send {media_play_pause}
```

It is also worth trying the other usual culprit - run the script as administrator.