# AHK sent media keys being blocked by Chrome

Tags: autohotkey

So I have a really basic script that makes for the media previous, play/pause, and next keys when I press the appskey and F7/F8/F9, however for some reason, its being blocked by my Chrome browser.

```
AppsKey & F7::      Send {Media_Prev}
AppsKey & F8::      Send {Media_Play_Pause}
AppsKey & F9::      Send {Media_Next}
```

This was meant to work with FooBar2000 and VLC Player, both of which work with the hotkeys when Chrome is not loaded. Prodikl had given an update in the link below in regards to how I found this out in the first place.

[autohotkey Media_Play_Pause not mapped to Pause but mapped to ^Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127315/autohotkey-media-play-pause-not-mapped-to-pause-but-mapped-to-space)

Anyone have any ideas on how to make this work while Chrome is open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

[Chrome Hijacking Your Media Keys? Here’s The Simple Fix](http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/)

I'm not currently using Google Play Music, but I had at one point installed it. After turning Google Play Music's shortcuts to "In Chrome," media hotkeys now work fine both through AHK and a keyboard with built in media keys.

This works on Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106.